# How to use Flask-Login when user info provide by remote service?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm building a Flask app and started using Flask-Login for authentication.  What troubles me is that Flask-Login calls the load_user callback for *every* request that flask handles.  Here is the example from https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#how-it-works:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    return User.get(userid)
```

To retrieve the user, I need to pass a session token a remote web service across a VPN, and the remote web service does a db query -- this results in noticeable latency on every web request.  My load_user looks something like this:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    # notice that I don't even use the userid arg
    try:
        # have to get session_token from session; why not 
        # just get the entire user object from session???
        token = session.get('session_token')
        user_profile = RestClient().get_user_profile(token)
        return User(user_profile['LDAP_ID'])
    except:
        return None
```

Seems like maybe I'm subverting the framework.  Could just store/retrieve user from session, so why bother to get it from the web service?  This option also seems to subvert Flask-Login, but eliminates latency and makes good use of session.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to cache session information using something like memcached or redis (look into [Flask-Cache](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/) for help).

You should have a key-value cache store that structures the cache like so:

key: sessionID
value: user object

This is what most frameworks do -- Flask-Login is a generic tool -- so you have to implement this yourself.

Incidentally, if you're looking for a way to abstract away that nasty LDAP stuff on the backend, you might want to check out https://stormpath.com -- they sync with LDAP servers, and provide a REST API on top of it. There's also a Flask library for interacting with it: [Flask-Stormpath](http://flask-stormpath.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: thanks for the info, we use redis for other stuff so may use that for caching sessions.  Funny you mention LDAP, we're almost done migrating from LDAP to a database.  LDAP is such a PITA to work with, and for our apps it provided almost no value.

Comment: Yah -- LDAP is pretty awful :( Lots of people get stuck with it for legacy reasons, but it's so annoying >< You should be fine using redis for key/value session storage -- that's probably your best bet.